# Group and sort a collection of collections using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, hql

I am looking to make a REST controller that will return a sorted list of various objects.

I have created a DTO to hold these collections like the following, but this will not work as it will group by entity:

```
public class AllReportsDTO {

private List<AReport> aReports;
private List<BReport> bReports;
private List<CReport> cReports;
...
}
```

I then have the following Domain objects

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a_report")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class AReport implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "title")
private String title;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "time_of_report")
private ZonedDateTime timeOfReport;
```

And one for each Report.

What I want to do is create an endpoint that will return a list of all these reports but in order of time of the report and not grouped by report. How can I achieve this?

I have tried writing it in the repository with a HQL query and grouping by time, but the issue is that each time field has a different name in each report which I can not alter due to this system being used in other places.

Comment: Make seperate class for the Json Representation of your "report" entity & use @JsonPropertyOrder

Comment: Hi Sujal, thank you very much for your reply. The Issue is that each report has very few variables in common, so it would be difficult to create the JSON represenation as a common view. The biggest issue is also that the variables names for the time are named differently which I can not change so it would be hard to order on.

Comment: I dont understand. First: a `Set` will make your ordering by time obsolete because it guarantees no order. You have to switch to `List`. Second: if there are different entities then select them by sepeartely and in each query you can order by the current time field.

Comment: But each report must have atleast "time of report" same right ? & Also @RobertNiestroj mentioned, you can't have Sets in here, go with Lists instead.

Comment: The issue is that I am looking to order all entities by their time, but not grouped together by entity. for example: A reportA happens at 2:31, a report B happens at 2:32 and another reportA at 2:33. I would like the returned result to return a list with reportA, then B then A.

Comment: Also, the DTO is for demonstration, not what I have written, I will change it to avoid confusion.

Comment: How about keep using HQL and "*rename*" the time field by using alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try a pure HQL solution, or a solution from your ORM. I would go to the Java way.

1. Add an interface

   ```
   public interface ITimedReport {
       ZonedDateTime getTime();
   }
   ```
2. Make all your report class implements this interface by returning their own timestamp
3. Add a method `getAllReports` on `AllReportsDTO`. 
   This method should fill a `List<ITimedReport>` with all reports, and then sort the list with a `Comparator<ITimedReport>`. This comparator would rely on the `getTime()` to compare.

You can add anything meaningfull for a report in the interface, like a getTitle, getDescription, ...

Comment: Thank you Genu! that is a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can create methode that sort your sets. Try to adept this one

```
Collections.sort( aReports, new Comparator<Object>() {
  public int compare(MyObject o1, Object o2) {
      return o1.getTimeOfReport().compareTo(o2.getTimeOfReport());
  }
});
```